# ¿Obtener valor seleccionado de un ViewPager?

Tags: android, kotlin

Estoy trabajando con ViewPager2, simplemente es un selector que me da a escoger entre las 5 vocales, pero ahora quiero obtener el valor de cual es la vocal actualmente seleccionada. He probado con `currentItem` pero no me da el valor, sino la posición, ¿como podría obtener el valor que contiene?

Answer (score 1):

Usando [ViewPager2](https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/viewpager2/widget/ViewPager2) obtén el elemento seleccionado mediante [getCurrentItem()](https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/viewpager2/widget/ViewPager2#getCurrentItem()) que
devuelve la página seleccionada actualmente, iniciando con el indice 0. Si no se puede seleccionar ninguna página porque no hay adaptador o el adaptador está vacío, devuelve com valor 0.

Ejemplo:

```
var  posicion: Int = mViewPager.getCurrentItem()
```

Comment: Justamente en el mensaje puse que ya probé eso. Pero no necesito la posición, necesito lo que contiene dicha posición. Es decir mi ViewPager unicamente muestra una serie de palabras, un listado de Strings, y quiero saber cual es la palabra que está seleccionada en ese momento, el nombre.

Comment: Esas palabras las tienes en un ArrayList? Como poblas el ViewPager? Agrega esa información a tu pregunta.

Comment: Correcto, dichas palabras las tengo en un ArrayList que le paso al adapter del ViewPager, un adapter custom.